# Is there any need to use await when setting data in firestore from cloudfunctions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a web app that is running quite slow and has a few cloud functions used to update/set values in firestore

When I update a value in the firestore database, should I await the completion of the request, or can I trust that the request was sent and the data will be updated?

In other words, with the below function, does the await statement do anything to help with computation, or does it just increase the CPU time I'm using?

```
exports.exampleFunction = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response)=> {
    await db.collection('users').doc(request.body.userID).update({
        username: request.body.username
    })
    response.send({done: true})
    return ;
})
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you should wait to complete the operation, it shouldn't take long to update a document in Firesotre :) ... if your request is slow you could be experiencing a "cold start"

Comment: From a technical perspective, you do bring up a VERY interesting question though.  If  a Cloud Function returns a response while there is asynchronous work going on ... does that terminate the async work?

Comment: @Bee Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62135503/15774176) where Doug has explained the consequences  of removing await from the function.

You can also  refer to the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) where the importance of managing the lifecycle of a function is explained.

> When you return a JavaScript promise to a function, that function keeps running until the promise is resolved or rejected. To indicate that a function has
> completed its work successfully, the promise should be resolved. To indicate an error, the promise should be  rejected. This means you only need to handle
> errors that you want to.